# SIMPLE LIST ITEM CHECKED ON RESTORE

Tags: android, listview, checkedlistbox

I am new to Android. I have a simple_list_item_checked list in my application which gives a list of time(clock time). The user selects a time and an alarm will be triggered at that particular time with a dialog box to cancel or snooze the alarm.I am able to store the checked item in this list when the activity is in onPause state. But when the user quits the application and starts a fresh one, I wanted to retain the checked state of the items which the user has already selected when he was using the app last time. Please help me with the concept. Would be great if you include some codes in your answer. If your answer is shared preference, please help me with some codes as in where should I set my preference and where should I get my preference. This is the last part of the app that is pending with me. Thanks in Advance !

Comment: It looks like you know the answer, but want somebody else to do the work for you. This is not what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: Looks like I know the answer ?? Then why would I post a question here ?? I'm pretty much confused on where to set the preference and where to retrieve .. And more over browsing through the net for various tutorials I only get preferences that can be set for a checkbox entity alone. But here I have a simple list of checkable items. I don't have any clue on how to set preference for this. If you can, help me on this .

Comment: Grrr.  It's not "codes".  There is one source code.  Write to SharedPreferences in onPause(), reload in onCreate().

Comment: Thanks simon. Ill see to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for the pedantic tone I used in the comment above. What I meant is that if someone gives you the solution for your specific problem it will only help you for that problem. Next time you encounter something similar you will need to ask for help again.

If you really want to understand the hints that [@Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/789657/simon) gave you, take a look at the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) and figure out how you can save and restore data using the `savedInstanceState` bundle or the SharedPreferences.

Comment: Hey mate !sorry for the delayed reply. Was busy with my work. Not a problem at all man! thanks for your words again.. Ill look into things that you have quoted in your comments. Will try to figure a way out to solve my problem. Thanks anyways.